# c# MemoryStream vs Byte Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a function, which generates and returns a MemoryStream. After generation the size of the MemoryStream is fixed, I dont need to write to it anymore only output is required. Write to MailAttachment or write to database for example.

What is the best way to hand the object around? MemoryStream or Byte Array? If I use MemoryStream I have to reset the position after read.

Comment: How often do you need to re-read the data?

Comment: It depends. Sometimes only once, sometimes 2-3 times.

Comment: If you pass a `Byte` array then are you creating a new `MemoryStream` everywhere you use it?

Comment: At the moment I use MemoryStream. I have a wrapper around MemoryStream and a method that convert MemoryStream to byte array.

Comment: How big are the results? That's the thing that matters most.

Comment: OK, that means you don't have to worry about fragmentation.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you have to hold all the data in memory, then in many ways the choice is arbitrary. If you have existing code *that operates on `Stream`*, then `MemoryStream` may be more convenient, but if you return a `byte[]` you can always just wrap that in a `new MemoryStream(blob)` *anyway*.

It might also depend on how big it is and how long you are holding it for; `MemoryStream` can be *oversized*, which has advantages and disadvantages. Forcing it to a `byte[]` may be useful if you are holding the data for a while, since it will trim off any excess; however, if you are only keeping it briefly, it may be counter-productive, since it will force you to *duplicate* most (at an absolute minimum: half) of the data while you create the new copy.

So; it depends a lot on context, usage and intent. In most scenarios, "whichever works, and is clear and simple" may suffice. If the data is particularly large or held for a prolonged period, you may want to deliberately tweak it a bit.

One additional advantage of the `byte[]` approach: if needed, multiple threads can access it safely at once (as long as they are reading) - this is not true of `MemoryStream`. However, that may be a false advantage: most code won't *need* to access the `byte[]` from multiple threads.

Comment: Interestingly, `MemoryStream` uses `byte[]` internally at any rate, so it becomes more of a discussion about what API is required - the `Stream` or the array.

Comment: @Adam exactly; the **oversized** internal `byte[]` is available via `GetBuffer()`, but then you need to be very careful not to look at the out-of-range bytes, which are pure garbage.

Comment: Thread safety is the main reason for asking this question. Other reason is that my code uses byte arrays as parameters.

Comment: @LuckyStrike then you'd do well to simply return `byte[]` via `ms.ToArray()`, or if you **really** want to avoid the extra copy, a `new ArraySegment<byte>(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length)`

Comment: ArraySegment may not be compatible (as parameter), ToArray runs the risk of fragmentation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, but to avoid the fragmentation, you'd have to use `GetBuffer()`, and if the buffer isn't 100% full (almost all cases), you'd have to use something *like* `ArraySegment<byte>` - maybe a `byte[]` plus `int length`.

Answer (score 9):

The MemoryStream class is used to add elements to a stream.
There is a file pointer; It simulates random access, it depends on how it is implemented. Therefore, a MemoryStream is not designed to access any item at any time.

The byte array allows random access of any element at any time until it is unassigned.

Next to the byte [], MemoryStream lives in memory (depending on the name of the class). Then the maximum allocation size is 4 GB.

Finally, use a byte [] if you need to access the data at any index number. Otherwise, MemoryStream is designed to work with something else that requires a stream as input while you just have a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a byte[] because it's a fixed sized object making it easier for memory allocation and cleanup and holds relatively no overhead - especially since you don't need to use the functions of the MemoryStream. Further you want to get that stream disposed of ASAP so it can release the possible unmanaged resources it may be using.

Comment: A `MemoryStream` **has** no unmanaged resources to release. Forcing it to a `byte[]` may take *more* memory, due to duplication. My point: it isn't quite that simple.