# Storing a file as a byte array or a stream in an object?

Tags: c#

I was wondering which way is a better way to store a file? As a property in an object using a `Stream`, or a byte array (`byte[]`)?

For example:

```
public class FileObject
{
     public string SomeMetaData {get; set;}
     public Stream Content {get; set;}
}
```

vs

```
public class FileObject
{
     public string SomeMetaData {get; set;}
     public byte[] Content {get; set;}
}
```

I have an object that stores some meta data about a file and it also has the file content of the file. This class will act as a container for the file so I can do some logic based on its meta data before I save it.

I know if I use Stream I have to call Dispose before I'm done with it, which makes it harder to pass the object around without worrying about its content being disposed. However I'm not sure if that is a real issue or there are other things that I need to keep in mind.

Comment: A `Stream` only represents operating on the data, not the data itself.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Unless it's a MemoryStream.

Comment: So your question is really depend on how you get your data. From file system, or from web API or from COM...

Comment: Currently I either get the data from a web api or read it from a byte array in a sql table (I'm trying to get rid of this sql table)

Comment: What's the maximum length of the data?

Comment: Currently it is configurable in a config file, but I would say somewhere around 20MB.

Comment: Perhaps this will help your decision: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11828678/2779990

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stream is a stateful object.
If two pieces of code use your class together, they will end up fighting over the stream's position, and will not work.

If that is at all likely to happen, you should definitely use a `byte[]`.

Comment: writing into a `byte[]` array has risks too in multithreaded environments.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, conceptually a Stream is a means of accessing the data, not the data itself. Depending on your use case, this may or may not be what you actually want.

If your intention is (as it sounds) to model the actual file with its data, then `byte[]` is probably better suited to your purpose. Any of your class' methods that operate on that data should create their own temporary `MemoryStream` instances inside their own `using` blocks.

If you *do* want to create a class with a Stream member (or any other disposable member), then you should almost always implement `IDisposable` on that class as well. (It's not that complicated if you're not dealing with any unmanaged resources. You don't need a finalizer with the full-blown dispose pattern in those cases, simply forwarding the `Dispose()` call to each disposable member is usually enough.)