# Confusion over using Stream vs byte[] for transferring file content

Tags: c#, file-io, stream, memorystream

What I want to achieve is to read a JPEG image from disk, resize it (reduce the resolution) and return the resulting image to a different module which is going to save the image to an AWS S3 bucket... I am confused whether I should return the resulting image in a `byte[]` or `MemoryStream`.

I have seen [this tutorial](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/basic-image-manipulation-in-c-sharp) and have written the following function which reads an image, resize it and returns the resulting image in a `byte[]`.

```
public byte[] GetResizedImage(string folderPath, string fileName)
{
    // read the original image from disk
    FileInfo originalImage = ReadFileFromDisk(folderPath, fileName);

    // resize the image, set width to 640px and respect original aspect ratio 
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(originalImage.OpenRead()))
    {
        int newWidth = image.Width;
        int newHeight = image.Height;
        float aspectRatio = image.Width / image.Height;

        if (image.Width > 640)
        {
            newWidth = 640;
            newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalConstants.NoOfPixelsForImageResizing / aspectRatio);
        }

        // resize image           
        Image thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        using (var thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            thumbnail.Save(thumbnailStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return thumbnailStream.ToArray(); // <-- return image in byte[]
        }
    }
}
```

I am not clear if it makes any difference to change the above code and return `MemoryStream` instead of `byte[]`? If I change the code to return `MemoryStream` then I need to change the last 3 lines to:

```
var thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream();
thumbnail.Save(thumbnailStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
return thumbnailStream;
```

This way, I won't be able to dispose of `MemoryStream`... not sure if this would be a bad practice?

The reason for this question is that my other module which saves the reduced image to an S3 bucket, accepts the file input as Stream:

```
SavetoS3bucket(Stream image, string name)
{
    // save image to S3 bucket
}
```

So I am not clear if I am better off passing a `Stream` or `byte[]` to the above method?

Comment: You can add the _using_ statement around the call to _GetResizedImage_ if you return a MemoryStream. Then it depends on the calling code.

Comment: Does `SavetoS3bucket` dispose the stream if it passed to it?

Comment: @user1672994: I have not implemented this yet... but I believe I can write it in such a way to dispose of the `stream` in `SaveToS3Bucket`... not really sure which is a better approach?

Comment: Take a look at [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828678/12217161). Hope it helps you to take your best decision.

Comment: Once you pass the stream to `SavetoS3bucket` then it's responsibility to cleanup the stream.

Comment: @user1672994 normally it is the code that creates the stream that should dispose it

Comment: @Steve - agree with you. But in this case, the `stream` is returned. If it's being returned then how caller can dispose it?

Comment: @user `using (var stream = MethodThatReturnsStream())` is how I'd probably use such a method.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for your comments. I think I will go with your first suggestion and return a `MemoryStream`... i.e. `using (var stream = GetResizedImage(...))`, I must have misunderstood your second comment though, you are saying the code that creates the `stream` should `dispose` it... so if I return the `stream`, the code creating the `stream` won't `dispose` it... are you able to clarify please?

Comment: No, I was commenting on the concept that _normally_ you should have a method that creates disposable objects, use them and finally destroy/dispose them. In my opinion it is dangerous to have a disposable object destroyed in some other part of your code. In your case this is not clearly possible, so you have a method that returns a disposable object and need to be enclosed in a using statement. Just do not forget about it.

Comment: what's so hard to call Dispose after SavetoS3bucket ? Even if SaveToS3bucket is Disposint itself, the implementation of Dispose does most often handle to be called multiple times.

Comment: @Holger: it's not hard, though it's something that one should not forget... and therefore could lead to bugs...

Comment: Sure but if you know, why ask a question ? Well you got several approaches how to handle it. "using" should be prefered, unlike calling dispose manually, the using also handles exceptions, by implicitly adding a try-finally-block, and finally disposes it's resource, also in case of exceptions.

Comment: @Holger Whether I'm aware that the question is not about `using vs try-catch`. but for the record, using "using" is not a good idea because of couple of reasons. First of all, `IL` will translate `using` blocks to `try-finally` block. It's better to write `try-catch-finally` manually with a little twist in it instead of forcing compiler to convert your code. Second, if there is an error in `try` block you cannot catch it. And third, if dispose method in `finally` block throw an error you're not gonna be informed and therefore you cannot catch it either.

Comment: @MasLoo, That's off topic here, but to recommend not to use using in general goes way too far. I have no idea why you say you cannot catch Exceptions. Try blocks can be nested unlimited. Compiler is also not converting any code, it's adding some. As any peace of writing in source code, will add some feature.

Comment: @Holger AFAIK you mentioned in your comment `the using also handles exceptions, by implicitly adding a try-finally-block`. `IL` sees `using` as `try-finally` if you write `try-catch` inside `using` block it's like wrapping `try-catch` by `try-finally` that is nonsense, no matter how many times you'll wrap it that way, you cannot catch errors thrown inside `finally` block. That is why I said isntead of write `using` or `using(try-catch)` it's better to write `try-catch-finally(try-catch)`. This way you can cover all errors, whether it's thrown inside `try` or `finally` block.

Comment: Yes, using includes, try finally, this is no reason not to use it. The guarantee is to have Dispose called, also in case of exceptions. Therefore you need the finally. I'm explaining you the IL, not the C# here !  Back to C#.
"Using" gives a variable scope, you don't have a reference to a disposed variable, you cannot do bad things any more.
I don't want to wrap and don't recommand to use try-catch, cause of "using" is already doing this. This is not about covering errors, it's about covering the dispose in case of error. Your Exception handling you do wherever you want.